# How to override laravel illuminate ServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I upgraded the php version and now loadViewsFrom method from **vendor/illuminate/support/ServiceProvider.php**
generate an error, because **$this->app->config['view']** is not an array.

```
protected function loadViewsFrom($path, $namespace)
{
    if (is_array($this->app->config['view']['paths'])) {
        foreach ($this->app->config['view']['paths'] as $viewPath) {
            if (is_dir($appPath = $viewPath.'/vendor/'.$namespace)) {
                $this->app['view']->addNamespace($namespace, $appPath);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->app['view']->addNamespace($namespace, $path);
}
```

How can I fix that without upgrade the laravel version and without modify the vendor file?

I tried to override the map class from composer autoload and run composer dump-autoload, but without success.

My composer looks like:

```
...
"autoload": {
    "exclude-from-classmap": ["vendor/illuminate/support/ServiceProvider.php"],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Illuminate\\": "app/illuminate/"
    }
},
...
```

In app/illuminate/support I added my custom ServiceProvider.php.

Also, I tried to map in bootstrap/app.php like:

```
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider::class,
    App\illuminate\support\ServiceProvider::class
);
```

The vendor class is still used.

Framework and php version:

```
Laravel Framework Lumen (5.6.4) (Laravel Components 5.6.*)

php version: 7.4.13
```

Answer (score 3):

If `$this->app->config['view']` is not an array then your problem lies in your [`config/view.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/view.php) file.

By default this file looks like this

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | View Storage Paths
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Most templating systems load templates from disk. Here you may specify
    | an array of paths that should be checked for your views. Of course
    | the usual Laravel view path has already been registered for you.
    |
    */

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Compiled View Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option determines where all the compiled Blade templates will be
    | stored for your application. Typically, this is within the storage
    | directory. However, as usual, you are free to change this value.
    |
    */

    'compiled' => env(
        'VIEW_COMPILED_PATH',
        realpath(storage_path('framework/views'))
    ),

];
```

As you can see, an `array` is returned. So you should better fix this instead of overriding the service provider.

Comment: Good point and I agrre with you, but I don't know why sometimes $this->app->config['view'] return null. I added a log:     protected function loadViewsFrom($path, $namespace)
    {
        Log::info(json_encode($this->app->config['view'])); ... And looks like: local.INFO: null  
local.INFO: {"paths":["\/var\/www\/html\/my-project\/resources\/views"],"compiled":"\/var\/www\/html\/my-project\/storage\/framework\/views"}  
local.INFO: null  
local.INFO: {"paths":["\/var\/www\/html\/my-project\/resources\/views"],"compiled":"\/var\/www\/html\/my-project\/storage\/framework\/views"}

Comment: once return null and once return correct values from config/view.php

Comment: Then you need to trace back the ones where it is null. Sorry,  but here we cannot debug your whole application. Rough guess: Something is modifying the configuration and set it to null.